# Make a plot using x and y data from two separate series object type in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, series, subplot

I have two series that look like this (in the variable explorer of spyder, excuse my being a novice to programming):

**s1:**

| Index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| B_D1 | 20 |
| B_D2 | 22.45 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| B_D60 | 998 |

**s2:**

| Index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| B_C1 | 96000 |
| B_C2 | 26000 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| B_C60 | 300 |

I would like to make a plot using the values in s1 (20, 22.45,...,998) as the x axis and the values in s2 (96000, 26000,...,300) as the y axis.

I think a new series s3 should be created with the values from s1 under a column titled "B_D" with row indices going from 0 to 59 and values from s2 under a column titled as "B_C" with row indices also going from 0 to 59 and then using `s3.plot(x='B_D', y='B_C', style='-')`, make the plot that I am looking for.

Comment: you mean pandas.series or other kinds of series or justa two list of tuples or dictionaries or whatsoever , please be specific

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If s1 and s2 are the same length, you could simply make the pandas series into a numpy array and then plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = s1.to_numpy()
y = s2.to_numpy()

plt.plot(x, y, '-.')

plt.show()
```

This would make a line plot with your data.